# The release to Sonatype is complete but is said to have no staging repository

Tags: scala, sbt, open-source, release, sonatype

If I release oss to sonatype, I will always say A when finished.

- sbt version 1.2.8

plugin versions

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "sbt-pgp" % "1.1.2-1")
addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-sonatype" % "2.4")
```

release steps

```scala
  releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
    checkSnapshotDependencies,
    inquireVersions,
    runClean,
    runTest,
    tagRelease,
    releaseStepCommandAndRemaining("+publishSigned"),
    ReleaseStep(action = Command.process("sonatypeRelease", _), enableCrossBuild = true)
  )
```

I see, it looks like you're trying to upload something to staging again. But all releases are complete. What does he want to do?

error

```
[info] Packaging /Users/xxxx/src/hoge/target/scala-2.12/hoge_2.12-1.3.0-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  published hoge_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com.huga/hoge_2.12/1.3.0/hoge_2.12-1.3.0-sources.jar
[info]  published hoge_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com.huga/hoge_2.12/1.3.0/hoge_2.12-1.3.0.pom.asc
[info]  published hoge_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com.huga/hoge_2.12/1.3.0/hoge_2.12-1.3.0-javadoc.jar
[info]  published hoge_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com.huga/hoge_2.12/1.3.0/hoge_2.12-1.3.0.pom
[info]  published hoge_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com.huga/hoge_2.12/1.3.0/hoge_2.12-1.3.0.jar
[info]  published hoge_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com.huga/hoge_2.12/1.3.0/hoge_2.12-1.3.0-sources.jar.asc
[info]  published hoge_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com.huga/hoge_2.12/1.3.0/hoge_2.12-1.3.0.jar.asc
[info]  published hoge_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com.huga/hoge_2.12/1.3.0/hoge_2.12-1.3.0-javadoc.jar.asc
[success] Total time: 71 s, completed 2019/07/11 5:41:36
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to hoge (in build file:/Users/xxxx/src/hoge/)
[info] Setting scala version to 2.11.12
[info] Set current project to hoge (in build file:/Users/xxxx/src/hoge/)
[info] Nexus repository URL: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local
[info] sonatypeProfileName = com.huga
[info] Reading staging repository profiles...
[info] Reading staging profiles...
[info] Closing staging repository [comhuga-1031] status:open, profile:com.huga(c180edb2bdcbc8) description: Implicitly created (auto staging).
[info] Activity open started:2019-07-11T09:39:15.266Z, stopped:2019-07-11T09:39:25.858Z
[info] repositoryCreated: id:comhuga-1031, user:giita, ip:202.32.2.196
[info] Activity close started:2019-07-11T09:42:05.862Z, stopped:
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Passed: signature-staging
[info]   Evaluate: profile-target-matching-staging
[info]     Passed: profile-target-matching-staging
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3
[info]      email: to:omarun_inori@yahoo.co.jp
[info] repositoryClosed: id:comhuga-1031
[info] Closed successfully
[info] Promoting staging repository [comhuga-1031] status:closed, profile:com.huga(c180edb2bdcbc8) description: Implicitly created (auto staging).
[info] Activity release started:2019-07-11T09:43:50.973Z, stopped:
[info]   Evaluate: id:nx-internal-ruleset, rule:RepositoryWritePolicy
[info]   Evaluate: RepositoryWritePolicy
[info]     Passed: RepositoryWritePolicy
[info]     Passed: id:nx-internal-ruleset
[info]  copyItems: source:comhuga-1031, target:releases
[info]      email: to:omarun_inori@yahoo.co.jp
[info] repositoryReleased: id:comhuga-1031, target:releases
[info] Promoted successfully
[info] Dropping staging repository [comhuga-1031] status:released, profile:com.huga(c180edb2bdcbc8) description: Implicitly created (auto staging).
[info] Dropped successfully: comhuga-1031
[info] Set current project to hoge (in build file:/Users/xxxx/src/hoge/)
[info] Setting scala version to 2.12.8
[info] Set current project to hoge (in build file:/Users/xxxx/src/hoge/)
[info] Nexus repository URL: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local
[info] sonatypeProfileName = com.huga
[info] Reading staging repository profiles...
[warn] No staging repository is found. Do publishSigned first.
[info] Reading staging profiles...
[error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: No staging repository is found. Run publishSigned first
[error]     at xerial.sbt.Sonatype$NexusRESTService.findTargetRepository(Sonatype.scala:528)
[error]     at xerial.sbt.Sonatype$SonatypeCommand$.$anonfun$sonatypeRelease$1(Sonatype.scala:281)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:142)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:137)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:181)
[error]     at $a8cba9c0e249bab031f6$.$anonfun$assemblySettings$9(build.sbt:28)
[error]     at sbtrelease.ReleaseStateTransformations$.$anonfun$runCrossBuild$2(ReleaseExtra.scala:319)
[error]     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
[error]     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:118)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:85)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:150)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$div$colon$(TraversableOnce.scala:150)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.$div$colon(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]     at sbtrelease.ReleaseStateTransformations$.$anonfun$runCrossBuild$1(ReleaseExtra.scala:318)
[error]     at sbtrelease.ReleasePlugin$autoImport$ReleaseKeys$.filterFailure$1(ReleasePlugin.scala:175)
[error]     at sbtrelease.ReleasePlugin$autoImport$ReleaseKeys$.$anonfun$releaseCommand$6(ReleasePlugin.scala:188)
[error]     at scala.Function$.$anonfun$chain$2(Function.scala:24)
[error]     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
[error]     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:118)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:85)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:150)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$div$colon$(TraversableOnce.scala:150)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.$div$colon(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]     at scala.Function$.$anonfun$chain$1(Function.scala:24)
[error]     at sbtrelease.ReleasePlugin$autoImport$ReleaseKeys$.$anonfun$releaseCommand$2(ReleasePlugin.scala:193)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:142)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:137)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:181)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:151)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:246)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:250)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:132)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:110)
[error]     at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:59)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:35)
[error]     at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:138)
[error]     at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:89)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: No staging repository is found. Run publishSigned first
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx